# How do I insert characters into white spaces using Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Forgive me, I am very new to Ruby and relatively new to programming in general.  My problem is probably not hard, but I have googled until my fingers bled looking for a solution and I just cant get it.

I have a line of text that looks like this:

`6 19 11 28 22 localhost G6UI ip0 cameraLink cameraLinkMissingScans 15116`

After all is said and done, I want it to look like this:

`6.19.2014,11.28.22,localhost,G6UI,ip0,cameraLink cameraLinkMissingScans 15116`

I have accomplished this in Bash (I am essentially just making a CSV file, with the time and date formatted the way I want it) but, for reasons to lengthy to explain, Id like to do it with Ruby.

I have a start, although its probably a bit sad:

`myLineOfText.sub!(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9]/,'\1.\2.')`

Which gives me this:

`6..19 11 28 22 localhost G6UI ip0 cameraLink cameraLinkMissingScans 15116`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I just need something to get me started.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did the `2014` come from??

Comment: This is actually a hard thing to do. If you don't know how the line of text is generated, you won't know how to parse it.

Comment: Please consider selecting the answer you found most helpful, unless, of course, none met your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure the format always remains the same, you can do:

`str.sub!(/(\d+) (\d+) (\d+)/,'\1.\2.\3').gsub!(/ /,',')`

Example:

```
str='6 19 11 28 22 localhost G6UI ip0 cameraLink cameraLinkMissingScans 15116'
str.sub!(/(\d+) (\d+) (\d+)/,'\1.\2.\3').gsub!(/ /,',')
puts str
=> "6.19.11,28,22,localhost,G6UI,ip0,cameraLink,cameraLinkMissingScans,15116"
```

Comment: Thats awesome! Thank you for the quick response. The only problem is I dont need commas all the way only up too "ip0". Like this:
6.19.2014,11.28.22,localhost,G6UI,ip0,cameraLink cameraLinkMissingScans 15116

Comment: The 2014 I am just inserting at this point so that the date is complete. I need to do some thinking about how to get the proper year in there later. Ugh

Answer (score 0):

With questions such as this one, the answer depends on what is fixed and what is variable in the data's format.  I have assumed:

- there are at least nine substrings separated with spaces
- substrings 0 and 1 (base 0) correspond to the month and year, and are to be combined with the literal "2014" to form a date of the form `dd.mm.2014`
- substrings 2-4 are to be joined with '.' and followed with ','
- substrings 5-7 are to be joined with ',' and followed with ','
- the remainder of the substrings are to be joined with a space

I don't think a regex is the right tool for the formating; rather just split the string on spaces and form the new string by using a series of `String#join`'s, combining the resulting substrings in the obvious way:

```
s = "6 19 11 28 22 localhost G6UI ip0 cameraLink cameraLinkMissingScans 15116"
a = s.split(' ')
#=> ["6", "19", "11", "28", "22", "localhost", "G6UI", "ip0", "cameraLink",
#    "cameraLinkMissingScans", "15116"]

a[0]+'.'+a[1]+'.2014,'+a[2..4].join('.')+','+a[5..7].join(',')+','+
  a[8..-1].join(' ')
#=> "6.19.2014,11.28.22,localhost,G6UI,ip0,cameraLink cameraLinkMissingScans 15116"
```

Comment: OH! I really like this. This will actually allow me to make some other alterations that I was trying to do. Very good! Thank you.
arco444 Your solution was working perfectly, so thank you again, but this one will allow me a little more versatility.